# implementing a spinner type object in a class as a subprocess

Tags: python, multithreading, class, process

I'm a total beginner and only started doing classes today, and im trying to make a sort of 'spinner' object i can call something like this: One of the things im confused about is whether to use 'thread', 'threading' or 'processes'. I just read somewhere that an instance of a thread costs 8meg, as this is a simple text spinner thing, it doesnt warrant using a huge amount of memory. My first question is which module should I use, and my second is how do implement this in a class so i can call it like this:

```
spin.start() - starts it

spin.stop() -  stops it

spin.cursor_invisible() - turns the cursor invisible

spin.cursor_visible() - cursor visible!
```

I copied some code and read some books but Im a bit confused, what I have so far is this: i put some comments in to show how ignorant I am. I have been reading a lot though, honest! Its kind of a large thing to get your head around.

```
spinner="▏▎▍▌▋▊▉█▉▊▌▍▎" #utf8

#convert the utf8 spinner string to a list
chars=[c.encode("utf-8") for c in unicode(spinner,"utf-8")]

class spin():   # not sure what to put in the brackets was (threading.Thread, but now im not sure whether to use processes or not)

    def __init__(self):
            super(spin, self).__init__() # dont understand what this does
            self._stop = threading.Event()

    def run (self):
            threading.Thread(target = self).run()
            pos=0
            while not self._stop:
                    sys.stdout.write("\r"+chars[pos])
                    sys.stdout.flush()
                    time.sleep(.15)
                    pos+=1
                    pos%=len(chars)

    def cursor_visible(self):
            os.system("tput cvvis")
    def cursor_invisible(self):
            os.system("tput civis")
    def stop(self):
            self._stop.set() #the underscore makes this a private variable ?
    def stopped(self):
            return self._stop.isSet()
```

Comment: Honest-honest? I think going from classes to parallel computing in 24 hours make little sense (even more so if you are considering multithreading, which - compared to multiprocessing - has additional and very subtle implications). From the code you posted it is quite clear you have little understanding of the basics of python programming. Don't get me wrong: your question is a legitimate one, and somebody will eventually answer... but you would probably learn quicker, better and with more fun if you would follow one of the many python tutorials that guide you in a progressive, smooth way! :)

Comment: less than 24 :) more like 2 :) thats totally the opposite way of how ive learned everything i know, weirdly. but each to their own. i figure out stuff in a fuzzy way, i tend to bombard myself with how it works and keep trial and error hacking stuff till it burns in. but yeah i agree im not very good :)

Comment: hey there mac, i just got it all worky! so hows that for proving you wrong! its true kids, you dont need to go through every tutorial bit by bit until youve understood every single thing before you write a program! you can just go ahead and type and learn as you go, in fact as i learn more about python, it seems thats what they intended in the first place. is fun really going through a tutorial ? no. fun is writing your own thing. </rant>

Comment: Fun is subjective, so if you had more of it this way... you definitively made the right choice in doing so. :) However today is 5/12, it took you over one week (and 21 questions SO, very few of them upvoted [=not showing good research effort / not being useful]) to solve a problem for which you could have acquired all the knowledge in probably one or two days following a tutorial. Again: I understand you are not a professional developer and learnt python for fun... so be my guest! :) But I would hardly say this is proof I was wrong... I never said you would have failed in the first place! :o

Comment: no way man ! :) which tutorial would teach me all the concepts in this http://pastebin.com/YfzMVj1i ? none of my questions have ever been downvoted im using stack overflow as its meant to be, to learn! i think considering the concepts and the fact its my first ever python program im not doing bad. did have fun though, shawn solved my greatest problem the other bits were just annoying.

Comment: and in fact several of my questions have received large upvotes. cheeky monkey. not that i care about votes. i will delete this account shortly and start again anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have altered your code slightly. Now it runs! First a commented version:

The first line tells python that this source file contains utf-8 characters

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Then you need to import all the stuff that you will eventually use. You dont have to do it at the top of the file like this, but I'm a C guy and this is how I like it...

```
import threading
import sys
import time
import os

spinner="▏▎▍▌▋▊▉█▉▊▌▍▎" #utf8

#convert the utf8 spinner string to a list
chars=[c.encode("utf-8") for c in unicode(spinner,"utf-8")]

class spin(threading.Thread):   # not sure what to put in the brackets was (threading.Thread, but now im not sure whether to use processes or not)
```

Threading is fine for this

```
    def __init__(self):
        super(spin,self).__init__() # dont understand what this does
```

Since you are overriding the **init** method of threading.Thread with your own init you need to call the parent class's init to make sure the object is properly initiated.

```
        self._stop = False
```

I changed this to a boolean. The threading.Event is overkill for this.

```
    def run (self):
        pos=0
        while not self._stop:
            sys.stdout.write("\r"+chars[pos])
            sys.stdout.flush()
            time.sleep(.15)
            pos+=1
            pos%=len(chars)

    def cursor_visible(self):
        os.system("tput cvvis")
    def cursor_invisible(self):
        os.system("tput civis")
    def stop(self):
        self._stop = True  #the underscore makes this a private variable ?
```

Sort of. It's not actually private, the underscore just tells everyone that it's bad form to acces it.

```
    def stopped(self):
        return self._stop == True
```

And finally a small test of the code:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    s = spin()
    s.cursor_invisible()
    s.start()
    a = raw_input("")
    s.stop()
    s.cursor_visible()
```

And here is the uncommented version...

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 

import threading
import sys
import time
import os

spinner="▏▎▍▌▋▊▉█▉▊▌▍▎" #utf8

#convert the utf8 spinner string to a list
chars=[c.encode("utf-8") for c in unicode(spinner,"utf-8")]

class spin(threading.Thread):   # not sure what to put in the brackets was (threading.Thread, but now im not sure whether to use processes or not)

    def __init__(self):
        super(spin,self).__init__() # dont understand what this does
        self._stop = False

    def run (self):
        pos=0
        while not self._stop:
            sys.stdout.write("\r"+chars[pos])
            sys.stdout.flush()
            time.sleep(.15)
            pos+=1
            pos%=len(chars)

    def cursor_visible(self):
        os.system("tput cvvis")
    def cursor_invisible(self):
        os.system("tput civis")
    def stop(self):
        self._stop = True  #the underscore makes this a private variable ?
    def stopped(self):
        return self._stop == True


if __name__ == "__main__":
    s = spin()
    s.cursor_invisible()
    s.start()
    a = raw_input("")
    s.stop()
    s.cursor_visible()
```

Comment: thankyou so much! awesome answer and works perfectly. really appreciate it.

Comment: oh cool, you make midi tracker type stuff, i used to play with that when i was little :) moved on to studios n stuff though and got logic , seemed easier :)

Comment: Yeah I did 5 years ago, in Java. I seriously doubt that that project will even run today.

Comment: oh in java! ha! cool! i use bidule by plogue a fair bit, or did before i got into python :) its kind of like max/msp with nice graphics although max has now been integrated into abelton which is a bit pants IMO, because i might not want to use ableton with it. i heard ableton is written in python which seems weird. probably wrong.

Comment: Next time I do something with music (no time now) I will probably try to build a harware synth out of a microcontroller or something. There is also some nice kits that seems like allot of fun, like the x0x

Comment: regarding this, my mate built a modular out of parts from the internet, hes got his circular sequencer going, nice toy and sounds pretty good! ;) since the code above, completely changed it round, and since then thought of another way of doing it better.