# simple passing of variables to classes

Tags: python, class, variables

Why doesn't this work ?

```
class spin(threading.Thread):  
        def __init__(self):
                super(spin,self).__init__()
                self._stop = False
        def run (self,var):
                self.var=var
                print self.var
        def echo (self,var):
                self.var=var
                print self.var

if __name__ == '__main__':

        s = spin()
        s.start('hello')
```

but this does?

```
    s = spin()
    s.echo('hello')
```

Im guessing its because the start sequence needs to be defined in the init ? but not sure how. someone asked for error codes from this:

```
    s.start('hello')
TypeError: start() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

Comment: I know [you deliberately want to skip the basics of python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8315249/146792), yet... your code is poorly indented. It should be 4 spaces, not 8 (see [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/))

Comment: Some traceback would be a nice gift to us... What's the error? What do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: i use tabs instead of 4 spaces, ill update the question now.

Comment: btw - im not deliberately skipping anything, Im trying to make sense of a huge subject whilst writing a massive program. its the way i learn. each part of the program has its own problems to work out, and now ive pretty much written it, i decided to try using classes for it and thats opened up a nice can of worms :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason `s.start('hello')` does not work is that the inherited `Threadin.start()` method takes no arguments other than `self`.

Calling `s.echo('hello')` does appear to work, but it calls the function in the context of the main thread instead of spawning a new thread.

One way to fix your code is by supplying `var` to the constructor:

```
import threading

class Spin(threading.Thread):  
    def __init__(self,var):
        super(Spin,self).__init__()
        self.var = var
    def run(self):
        print self.var

if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = Spin('hello')
    s.start()
    s.join()
```